# Theos instance method calling

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, jailbreak, theos

I have searched for an answer to this and cannot find one.

How would I call an instance method in the same class I am hooking in my Theos tweak?
If I was using standard Xcode i would use the self method i.e.-

```
[self method:arg];
```

But in a theos tweak this says cannot find the method, even if i hook that method.

**Example:**

```
%hook classimhooking

-(void)methodimhooking
{
    [classimhooking methodiwanttocall];
    [self methodiwanttocall];
    %orig;
}

-(void)methodiwanttocall
{
    %orig;
}

%end
```

The `methodiwanttocall` is there and i can hook to it, just not call it. 
I have tried adding a new method with `%new` and calling that but it is not found, i have tried the same with a delay, but it is not found.
I have tried defining a variable of my class and calling that but it doesn't work.

I can also see that you can grab iVars directly, but this doesn't work with methods.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: your question is not very clear. suggestion write this [self method:arg]; in viewdidload method of you controller. viewdidload is call whenyour viewcontroller is loaded.   & what are these %orig.

Comment: These are Theos directives that call the original method of the class i am hooking. This question is only relative to theos as what you wrote will indeed work in standard objective c.

Comment: im really sorry. i did not know that. will try to answer you asap. thanks

Comment: Do you want to call the method you are hooking or another method?

Comment: Another method in the class i am hooking.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to call a method on the object you just hooked, you can use [`performSelector`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/performSelector%3a) (or [`performSelector:withObject:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/performSelector%3awithObject%3a) if it has an argument), which should be something like that:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(methodiwanttocall)];
```

Comment: Although this compiles fine, the method doesn't get called. 
I have tried a few methods but none are called. 
Does self need to be changed as self would refer to tweak.xm not the hooked class?

Comment: I think you can refer to `self` is it is actually the first parameter that is passed to the function and therefore should be available... It's not clear to me why it doesn't work, but I will be able to check that soon enough

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to dig an old thread. I may have an idea about the issue here. In case anyone with the same issue comes across this.

The problem is that the compiler does not know there is such a method, even there is. The way to deal with it is to import the header at the top of the code.

```
#import <classimhooking>
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12433200)

Comment: @ozgur: The beginning is an explanation of the problem.; the end is a solution.  Why should it be a comment instead of an answer?